# What are the co-ordinates of generator G in his uncompressed form on secp256k1?

Tags: secp256k1

I was looking at [BitcoinWiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) and it says that G, in it's uncompressed form, has a value of:
G = 04 79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B 16F81798 483ADA77 26A3C465 5DA4FBFC 0E1108A8 FD17B448 A6855419 9C47D08F FB10D4B8
Since it's uncompressed, it should contain information about X, but Y as well. How can I determinate those co-ordinates out of this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `04` first byte header indicates this is an uncompressed point (`02` indicates compressed).

From there, it is simply an `x` followed by `y` representation - The first 32 bytes are `x`, the following 32 bytes are `y`. Therefore,

```
x = 79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B 16F81798
y = 483ADA77 26A3C465 5DA4FBFC 0E1108A8 FD17B448 A6855419 9C47D08F FB10D4B8
```

More details on how compact elliptic point representations work can be found in [this](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-jivsov-ecc-compact-05.html) spec.

Comment: (For the sake of completeness) Both 2 and 3 indicate compressed form.

Comment: Correct, details on the encoding can be found in the very short and digestable SEC-1: https://www.secg.org/SEC1-Ver-1.0.pdf